# I have some problem when I upgrade my react-native version 0.70

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, mobile

this is error. please help me how to fix it!!! I was clean my cache but It dont work!!!

ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes ERROR Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegis try.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered calla ble JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler , RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter. A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is i ncorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes ERROR Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegis try.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered calla ble JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler , RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter. A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is i ncorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes

Comment: How to sole it i was described here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34688#issuecomment-1280457682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete your `node_modules` directory and `run npm  i`
- For Android `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..` for iOS remove `Podfile.lock` (windows) `cd android && gradlew clean && cd ..` For iOS `cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod cache clean --all && pod install && cd ..`
- Run `react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: thanks for the help. I was fixed this error. because the "react-native-check-version", i dont know why this dont work

Comment: For iOS, removing Podfile.lock is also necessary